# Performance Considerations When Collecting Information from an ArrayList of Objects

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist

I am writing a small program that collects information from a text file, in which the information on each line is separated by `|`. I've written a file reader class that creates an object with data members corresponding to the information on each line, then the object is put into an ArrayList.

Now I want to perform data analysis using the objects in the ArrayList, say, I want to find the average value of a specific attribute. Is it preferable to use a loop that traverses each element in the ArrayList and add the attribute value into a variable, then get the average using `[totalValue variable] / [ArrayList size]`?

The file I have here has over 60,000 lines. And I don't just want to do averaging. Are there any performance issues? Thanks so much.

Comment: Write the code and _then_ determine whether or not your code performs well. Chances are that your file I/O is going to take way more time than calculating any reasonable statistic that I can think of anyway. **Edit:** also, [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/audiofool/archive/2007/06/14/the-rules-of-code-optimization.aspx)

Comment: If you had a few hundred million or billions of rows I would suggest using binary format which is memory mapped but for 60 K entries, I would just make sure each file is read a minimum of times. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing the average necessarily requires looking at every element. Thus there is nothing wrong with using a loop.

Also bear in mind that for this type of computation, 60K elements is nothing.